# build gcc from source on old MBP with intel core 2 duo processor

Tags: gcc, homebrew, gfortran, macos-catalina

I am trying to build GCC from source which fails. The device I am working with is an old MacBook Pro 5,3 mid 2009 model with an Intel Core 2 Duo 2.66 GHz processor running macOS 10.15.7 Catalina.

First, I installed GCC via Homebrew. However, due to some other reason (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67130093/f951-internal-compiler-error-illegal-instruction-4-when-installing-packages-i) post) I would like to build GCC from source. When executing the command

```
brew reinstall --build-from-source gcc
```

I get the following error message

```
brew reinstall --build-from-source gcc
==> Downloading https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/formula-patches/6a83f
Already downloaded: /Users/Manuel/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/c0b9dca392d2e8496747001f634c04a4bc2f5c63672b963f3c4f217e70aaa258--bigsur_2.patch
==> Downloading https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-10.2.0/gcc-10.2.0.tar.xz
Already downloaded: /Users/Manuel/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/c8d4ca732a98ae691d04472b15de6d9e06a09016499af6ff16c4f55081bfc6b9--gcc-10.2.0.tar.xz
==> Reinstalling gcc 
==> Patching
==> Applying bigsur_2.patch
patching file gcc/config/host-darwin.c
patching file gcc/config/darwin-c.c
patching file gcc/config/darwin-driver.c
patching file gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/darwin-minversion-link.c
patching file gcc/config/darwin-driver.c
patching file gcc/config/darwin-driver.c
patching file libsanitizer/configure.tgt
patching file gcc/configure
Hunk #1 succeeded at 15485 (offset -5 lines).
patching file libatomic/configure
patching file libbacktrace/configure
patching file libcc1/Makefile.am
patching file libcc1/Makefile.in
patching file libcc1/configure
patching file libcc1/configure.ac
patching file libffi/configure
patching file libgfortran/configure
patching file libgomp/Makefile.in
patching file libgomp/configure
patching file libhsail-rt/configure
patching file libitm/configure
patching file libitm/configure.tgt
patching file libobjc/configure
patching file libphobos/configure
patching file libquadmath/configure
patching file libsanitizer/configure
patching file libsanitizer/configure.tgt
patching file libssp/configure
patching file libstdc++-v3/configure
patching file libtool.m4
patching file libvtv/configure
patching file zlib/configure
==> ../configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0_4 --libdir=/usr/local/Cel
==> make BOOT_LDFLAGS=-Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names
Last 15 lines from /Users/Manuel/Library/Logs/Homebrew/gcc/02.make:
/bin/sh ../../gcc/../move-if-change tmp-opinit.h insn-opinit.h
build/genattrtab ../../gcc/common.md ../../gcc/config/i386/i386.md insn-conditions.md \
        -Atmp-attrtab.c -Dtmp-dfatab.c -Ltmp-latencytab.c
/bin/sh ../../gcc/../move-if-change tmp-opinit.c insn-opinit.c
echo timestamp > s-opinit
build/genautomata ../../gcc/common.md ../../gcc/config/i386/i386.md \
      insn-conditions.md > tmp-automata.c
make[3]: *** [s-attrtab] Illegal instruction: 4
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/bin/sh ../../gcc/../move-if-change tmp-automata.c insn-automata.c
echo timestamp > s-automata
rm gcc.pod
make[2]: *** [all-stage1-gcc] Error 2
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

READ THIS: https://docs.brew.sh/Troubleshooting

These open issues may also help:
gcc 10.3.0 https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/74843
```

where obviously something is wrong. Unfortunately, I do not know where to continue resolving this issue. Very thankful for any help!

Manuel

Comment: There are two links for some reading suggested at the bottom of the output you copied here: "
READ THIS: https://docs.brew.sh/Troubleshooting" "These open issues may also help:
gcc 10.3.0 https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/74843" Are you sure you read those links?

Comment: Hi, yes thank you for pointing that out. I have read through some of the commits on Github and in the Homebrew documentation. However, I am not very familiar with that and find it difficult. Hence, I was hoping that maybe someone here could help me trying to find the problem and then build gcc from source...